# Imploding an array into a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

so I have a blog system, and i want to build a section for "related news", I am not making a 'Tags' system but just simply searching and storing the current title of the article (which is pulled from the database) in a string and exploding it to be able to later put all the words into a query, that later query will search all titles in the database to find any of those words, and if it does, it will return the title in a list. Here is the relevant code:

```
// note to stackoverflow peeps, $row_object_title is just the title that is pulled form the database
$row_object_title_lower = strtolower($row_object_title);
$keywords = explode(" ",$row_object_title_lower);
```

Code that is run later on the page:

```
$keywords_imploded = implode("','",$keywords);
$myquery = sql_query("SELECT object_title FROM table WHERE object_title IN ('$keywords_imploded')
```

Now i try to list the titles by printing the title out, but nothing is display.

I am sure there is matching titles in the database.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you're going to want to add some [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to that before you create a serious nightmare [injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: echo out $myquery to tell what is going wrong

Comment: @Askanison4 this is displayed: Resource id #17

Comment: you need to echo out the query STRING, e.g. `$sql = "SELECT ..."`, you're echoing out the query RESULT.

Comment: @MarcB so where is my string? sorry im confused. i dont have $sql = "...." i only have $myquery = sql_query("Select ... ");

Comment: build your query string FIRST into a variable, then  use that variable for the query call. `$sql = "SELECT ..."; $result = mysql_query($sql);`.

Comment: is object_title the title of the article? If so it looks like your trying to find the object_title in the list of words, which I'm guessing isn't correct. is it that you want to find any titles that contain one or more of those keywords?

Comment: @Boreded Yes i want to find titles that contain one or more of those, and why you say it looks like its doing the opposite?

Comment: @MarcB here is what i get: SELECT object_title, published_date, created_date, url, page_style FROM webmanage_objects WHERE object_title IN ('the','best','free','file','viewing/converting','software','for','your','windows','pc') AND parentid=564 AND is_visible=1 AND archived=0 ORDER BY published_date DESC LIMIT 0,10

Comment: The IN clause will look for what is on the left in the list of values on the right. For example: WHERE id IN (2,3,5) - if id is in that list it will return true. In your case it is the opposite. It is likely you will have to build the query using several of these: object_title LIKE %keyword%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as though you have misunderstood how the IN clause works.

The IN clause will look for what is on the left in the list of values on the right. For example: WHERE id IN (2,3,5) - if id is in that list it will return true. In your case it is the opposite.

Something like this should work for what your after but there are likely to be better alternatives.

```
$sql = '';
foreach ($keywords AS $keyword)
{
    if ($sql != '')
        $sql .= ' OR ';

    $sql .= "object_title LIKE '%$keyword%'";
}

$query = 'SELECT object_title FROM table WHERE '.$sql;
```

% is a wildcard.

Just please remember to escape the values first.

Answer (score 9):

Your array of keywords is generated with:

```
$keywords = explode(" ",$row_object_title_lower);
```

What if you have a title like "My Super Blog Post"? You're going to get:

```
$keywords = array( "My", "Super", "Blog", "Post" );
```

Later on, you query using those values imploded together:

```
$keywords_imploded = implode("','",$keywords);
$myquery = sql_query("SELECT object_title FROM table WHERE object_title IN ('$keywords_imploded')
```

The `SELECT` query is going to look like this:

```
SELECT object_title FROM table WHERE object_title IN ( 'My', 'Super', 'Blog', 'Post' );
```

I don't think that's going to find anything.

You need to re-evaluate how you're handling the list of titles (I think that's what you're going for, right?).

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$keywords_imploded = join("','", $keywords);
$myquery = sql_query("SELECT object_title FROM table WHERE object_title IN ($keywords_imploded)
```

Comment: `IN('$keywords_imploded')` -- if you used implode without the two inverted comma's like in OP this would break

Comment: I wish i could downvote you, that is for integers only, strings need the two quotes.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, so all you did was replace implode with "join()" ??? you do realise join is just an alias for implode

Comment: @user3332590 I also removed the single quotes from the IN clause

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer? This will not work
EDIT: bloody hell, people keep ninja editing the posts when I'm replying. No longer marked as answer

Comment: @Askanison4 I don't see any evidence suggesting this was ever marked as the answer, and it is not now. The only voting activity on it is two down votes.

Comment: It was... I got a message in my inbox. Clicked it and saw it was marked as accepted. 5 seconds later it was gone...

Comment: @superphonic lol thanks, at least I know I wasn't losing my mind there :p

Comment: Ahhh, ok; More than likely that was just a mis-click on the part of user3332590; Such a 'fleeting' period would not have shown up on the reputation history, explaining why I didn't see it! /cc @Askanison4

Comment: @Askanison4 No worries... On a side note, the reputation tab on your profile says you have 747, but under you profile picture and on your various answers, it says 75??

Comment: @superphonic hahaha there's always one!